# Is it not unfair for humanity to suffer based upon your past life karma which you aren’t aware of

Tags: karma, rebirth, ramanujacharya, manuscripts, yoga-vashishtha

I just feel its really unfair if life doesn’t give a chance for a human being to redeem his/her past life bad karma. If our past life bad karma can’t be escaped, at least shouldn’t we know what were our past life actions? I just want to know your views

Comment: I think the major reason why we can't remember our past lives has nothing to do with fairness. I think the main reason it is really hard for your body to convince you you are straight if you remember being attracted to other genders. Thus animals like humans have evolved a (painful) way of forgetting your past lives, so you can children and continue your genes.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it not unfair for humanity to suffer based upon your past life karma which you aren’t aware of

Just because you don't remember what you did, doesn't mean you didn't do it. Everyone is getting rewarded with suffering or happiness based on what they did previously. It does not matter whether you remember it or not.

> I just feel its really unfair if life doesn’t give a chance for a human being to redeem his/her past life bad karma. If our past life bad karma can’t be escaped, at least shouldn’t we know what were our past life actions?

To an extent, we do know what sins or merits we did based on the consequence we are experiencing now. For example:

> Manu [11.48](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201927.html) - Evil-minded men suffer disfigurement,—some from evil deeds committed during the present life and others from those committed in former lives

> [11.49](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201928.html) - The stealer of gold has disfigured nails; the drinker of wine, black teeth....etc.

From these, we can do the appropriate prayaschitti (penance/repentance):

> Manu [11.53](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201929.html) - Because persons with sins unexpiated are born with disgraceful marks, therefore expiatory rites shall always be performed, for the purpose of purification.

But for other sins that we don't remember or know about, regular spiritual and religious practice will destroy all those sins, and so we don't have to worry about their consequences manifesting.

Answer (score 0):

Just because one is Unaware doesn't mean one has paid for ones actions. Jivas are Anadi Baddh According to bramha Sutra (2.1.35) which means they are conditioned by karma since time without a beginning. If the inflictions of Beginingless lives were to be made aware to a human being, they would probably panic & die on the spot.  Hence whatever is necessary is made them aware & Bhagvan awards good & bad accordingly. One should understand it to be our past actions results & try to learn from the inflictions & try to be better person. This Karma Bandhan ultimately leads a person with the desire to know how to be eternally free of all miseries. This is when they start searching for God Conciousness